# Получить по одной записи из таблицы для каждого имени SQL

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая таблица, сгруппированная и отсортированная. Теперь мне нужно для каждого левого имени оставить только самую первую строку. Т. е. в таблице со скрина должно остаться 2 строки:

avtobus mashina 2

chelovek ivanov 1

Comment: Понятие "первая строка" требует указания сортировки, при которой эта строка будет первая. Вот и укажите такую сортировку... Да, текущее местоположение при выводе на экран - не подходит!

Comment: @Akina дайте же человеку хорошие подсказки

Comment: @rotabor Запросто. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за полезную информацию, мне было интересно почитать. Что касается обсуждаемого вопроса: если бы автор мог выполнить что-то из тех рекомендаций, он бы тогда сам смог ответить на свой вопрос. А человеку просто помощь нужна. И нужно постараться понять, в чём у человека проблема. Я подумал и ответил так, как понял, в чём у ChetNePolichaetsa затруднения.

Comment: @Akina Я нашёл решение. Нетревиальная, по-моему, задача.

Comment: @rotabor Задача - тривиальная. Но в текущей постановке - сильно недоопределённая. Автор, конечно, сказал, что данные отсортированы - но до сих пор не удосужился сообщить, как именно. Ваши предположения о выражении сортировки, возможно, верны, но только возможно. И вообще, по-моему, автор забил на свой вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Подсказка: задача состоит из двух подзадач:

1. Выбрать уникальные имена из первой колонки.
2. Выбрать первую запись из отсортированной таблицы для каждого такого имени.

Первая подзадача решается с помощью DISTINCT, а вторая с помощью FIRST.

**UPD.** Подсказки оказались так себе. Ох, и намучился я с этой штукой.
Вот решение: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8697/17

```
СREATE TABLE khrntn(
Col1 varchar(55),
Col2 varchar(55),
Col3 int
);

INSERT INTO khrntn VALUES
('avtobus', 'slon', 1),
('avtobus', 'zemelya', 2),
('avtobus', 'mashina', 2),
('avtobus', 'ivanov', 1),
('chelovek', 'slon' , 1),
('chelovek', 'ivanov' , 1),
('chelovek', 'zemelya' , 1),
('chelovek', 'mashina' , 1);
```

Решение:

```
SELECT Col1 AS NCol1, MIN(Col2) AS NCol2, MCol3 AS NCol3
FROM khrntn INNER JOIN (SELECT Col1 AS MCol1, MAX(Col3) AS MCol3
    FROM khrntn
    GROUP BY Col1) AS M ON Col1=MCol1 AND Col3=MCol3
GROUP BY Col1, MCol3
ORDER BY Col1;
```

Результат:

NCol1     NCol2    NCol3

avtobus   mashina  2

chelovek  ivanov   1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8697/20

Comment: @Akina сразу видно руку мастера. Понумеровать записи в группах - тоже хитрый ход

Comment: Вы явно пришли из мира алгоритмических языков и до сих пор мыслите итерациями. Поэтому задача кажется сложной, а моё решение - уровнем мастера. Это не так.